# Expectation of trial numbers on Multinomial distribution.

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Player extracts card from the deck (which has infinite number of size) to obtain one of $k$ colors of cards. The possibility that the player pick a card with $i$th color is given by $p_i>0$. Of course, $\sum_{i=1}^{k}p_{i} = 1$. If you collect at least one card from all colors, then we call you completed *one set of cards*. After certain number of trials (as the player want to end), dealer gives player $m$ dollars, where $m$ is the number of set of cards the player have completed. My object is to calculate the expectation value of number of trials to get $m$ dollar, where $m$ is given.

To rewrite it more mathematically:

Let $X_1, X_2, \dots, X_k$ be multinomial distribution with probability $p_i>0$ respectively. Let $g(k,m)$ be the least number of trials which making $\min(X_i)=m$. $g(k,m)$ forms a distribution of the number of trials, namely $n$. What is the explicit formula of $E(g(k,m))$?

At first, I tried the simplest case: when $k=2$, the probability that after exactly $n$ trials we get $m$ dollars is $$P(X_{1}=m-1,X_{2}=n-m)\times p + P(X_{1}=n-m,X_{2}=m-1)\times (1-p)$$
$$={n\choose m-1} p^{m}(1-p)^{m}(p^{n-2m}+(1-p)^{n-2m})$$
Therefore:
$$E(g(2,m))=\sum_{n=2m}^{\infty}{n\choose m-1} np^{m}(1-p)^{m}(p^{n-2m}+(1-p)^{n-2m})$$
Especially, $E(g(2,1))=\frac{p^{2}-p+1}{p(1-p)}$, which attains minimum at $p=\frac{1}{2}$, and this result fits well, since the difference between probabilities from extracting cards of different colors increase, making one set with given number of trials will be significantly harder. One of my conjecture is that $E(g(k,m))$ attains minimum value when $p_{1}=p_{2}=\cdots=p_{k}=\frac{1}{k}$.

But I failed to figure out the general case of $k$, since it requires too many number of calculations of infinite sums over binomial coefficients.

Also, I predict that, by intuition, $E(g(k,m))$ will behave like $\frac{m}{\min(p_i)}$ asymptotically as $m \to \infty$, since as the number of trials $n$ get large, the number of cards of each colors will be closer to $np_1, np_2, \ldots, np_k$. But it also seems too hard to prove..

Can I get your help? Thanks.